# MATLAB - transfer variables between callback and main program without guidata

Tags: matlab, callback, serial-communication

I am setting up a serial communication in matlab without GUI.

The serial initialisation looks like this (main program):

```
handles.s = serial('COM10' ,'BaudRate', 9600);
    set(handles.s,'Terminator','CR');
    set(handles.s,'Timeout',1);
    set(handles.s, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode', 'byte');
    set(handles.s, 'BytesAvailableFcnCount', 1);
    set(handles.s, 'BytesAvailableFcn', {@serialEventHandler, handles});
fopen(handles.s);
```

I am reading the buffer with a callback function (serialEventHandler)

```
function serialEventHandler(serialConnection, ~, handles)
    bytes = get(serialConnection, 'BytesAvailable');
    if(bytes > 0 ) % we may have alread read the data
        handles.data = fscanf(serialConnection)
        % fwrite(handles.appenderFile, handles.data); (not relevant here)
    end
end
```

For some reason, the callback does not update my handles structure and I am unable to access the serial data the main code. I understand this is the role of guidata(hobject, handles) in a GUI application, but is there a way to do this without GUI?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the documentation for [Sharing Data Between Workspaces](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html). Two of the options there should work for you, depending on where `serialEventHandler` is with respect to your main code:

- **For functions in separate files:** You will need to use [`global`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variables to share your `handles` structure between them. In your main program:

  ```
  global handles
  %... Initialize handles ...
  set(handles.s, 'BytesAvailableFcn', @serialEventHandler);  % Don't have to pass it
  ```

  And in `serialEventHandler`:

  ```
  function serialEventHandler(serialConnection, ~)  % Don't have to pass it
    global handles
    %... Rest of code ...
  end
  ```
- **For functions in the same file:** You can [nest one function inside the other](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), allowing them to share access to variables without having to pass them as input or output arguments:

  ```
  function main

    %... Initialize handles ...
    set(handles.s, 'BytesAvailableFcn', @serialEventHandler);  % Don't have to pass it
    %... Rest of main code ...

    function serialEventHandler(serialConnection, ~)  % Don't have to pass it
      %... serialEventHandler code ...
    end

  end
  ```

There is a third option as well (not mentioned in the above documentation on sharing data), but it could be substantially more work to implement: [Creating your own class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/user-defined-classes.html) to use in place of your `handles` structure and deriving from the [`handle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html) class to give it reference-like (i.e. pointer-like) behavior. Although creating a new class would be more involved, it would allow you to pass your `handles` object to any function without having to return a modified version. Your code above would likely remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative method to the ones well described by @gnovice, you could always write the variable contents to a file and read them in other parts of code.